# array_mask, Seeking alternative code

Tags: php

**I would really love to hear your critiques on:**

- Code quality
- Code clarity
- More efficient alternative code

Code:

```
function array_mask(array $source, array $filter){
    foreach ($source as $key => $value){
        if (!isset($filter[$key])){
            if (array_search($key, $filter) !== false){
                continue;
            }
            unset($source[$key]);
        } else {
            if (is_array($source[$key])){
                $source[$key] = array_mask($source[$key], $filter[$key]);
            }
        }
    }
    return $source;
} 


$source = array(
    'page' => array(
        'q' => 'alkflsdj',
        'x' => 1,
        9   => 'm'
    ),
    'news' => 7
);
$filter = array(
    'page' => array(
        9
    ),
    'news'
); 

$result = array_mask($source, $filter);
var_dump($result);
```

Result:

```
array
  'page' => 
    array
      9 => string 'm' (length=1)
  'news' => int 7
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use built-in functions instead. Like this for example:

```
function array_mask(array $source, array $filter)
{
    $source = array_intersect_key($source, $filter);

    foreach ($source as $key => $value)
        if (is_array($value))
            $source[$key] = array_mask($source[$key], $filter[$key]);

    return $source;
}

$source = array(
    'page' => array(
        'q' => 'alkflsdj',
        'x' => 1,
        9   => 'm'
    ),
    'news' => 7
);
$filter = array(
    'page' => array(
        9 => ''
    ),
    'news' => ''
);

var_dump (array_mask($source, $filter));
```

Comment: I had this idea, but for some reason she didn't like. Now like normal.

Answer (score 0):

Looks good to me, but you can make a small optimization:

change this

```
        if (array_search($key, $filter) !== false){
            continue;
        }
        unset($source[$key]);
```

to

```
        if (array_search($key, $filter) === false){
            unset($source[$key]);
        }
```

Comment: Just a suggestion, you might want to explain why you are suggesting the change.  Doing so will greatly increase the value of this answer.